# Is there anyway to bind multiple values to value field of a listbox -C# and ASP>NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a listbox named lbselectedcom in my web page. and i am binding some data to this list box by using a data table.  this datatable named dt have 3 fields -name,ID,Score

```
        lbSelectedCom.DataTextField = "Name";
        lbSelectedCom.DataValueField = "ID";          

        lbSelectedCom.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        lbSelectedCom.DataBind();
```

It works fine.Now i want to get score of the corresponding name with their ID. ID will get easily by using selected value property. Is there any way to bind Score field like ID in datavaluefield?? So that i can easily access score of each selected item like accessing ID by using selected value property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column to your datatable. And set the value of that column to be concatenation of ID and score separated by some delimiter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(VS.71).aspx

Comment: can i add new column to datatable from codebehind using expression???Can you pls give me an example?

Comment: The link has the example at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to create a new view from dt, apply a filter on the ID selected, get the record and the field's value you need from the new view.. you can finally even choose to keep the new view and just refresh its filter condition for further selection values.

Advantage of this method would be that you can get to 'any' field of the selected item's corresponding datatable row.